# Can I use ender chests to transfer items from the end?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Me and my friend found our first stronghold and activated the end portal. But wanted to wait with going there as we didn't know what to expect. Silverfish wanted none of that waiting and pushed us both into the end portal.

We both died, but at least i was able to go back and get most of my stuff and i'm now hiding under ground. Can we create an ender chest in our house, go to the end and place an ender chest there and transfer all my gear before I die? Got full diamond armor and loads of enchants and would hate to lose it all.

Comment: My friend was not able to find endermen, get pearls and make ender chests, so I ended up forcing the fight with the dragon. Died 5-6 times, but never to the void, so was able to re-collect my stuff and finally kill the mofo. Btw: Laddering to the top of the caged crystals while being attacked by a dragon sucks.

Comment: Tip for future reference: You don't have to place the ender chest in the house first. You can place it in the end, put your stuff in, die, and when you re-spawn, place your ender chest, and you can get the stuff.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Ender_Chest, it does work that way.

> If two Ender Chests are placed and two of an item was put in one, when the chest with the items in is opened, there will be one of the item in that chest and one of the same item in the other chests, acting as an image. This feature also works among the different worlds: Overworld, Nether, and the End.

Comment: I do believe it is also Player basted, is it not? So that If One player puts items in there, they are inaccessible to any other player. This would be important if you want one player to drop stuff into it and then have someone else pick it up/confirm it is there from the other side before you died.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**, your items will be transported *anywhere* in the world, including The End, The Nether, or anywhere else.
Be careful, though, that what you placed in an Ender Chest can only be picked up by you, and nobody else. So you can't transfer your items to your friend this way.

Comment: Also be careful, the Ender Dragon destroys some blocks it comes into contact with. It may destroy the Ender Chest.

Comment: Yes, it may destroy it, but the items will still be stored in a cloud-like storage. I mean that when you put another ender chest, you find your items there. @NeilSlater

Answer (score 2):

Yup, they work between dimensions transferring itens.